# how to filter ls output using find

Tags: linux, filter, find

I am trying to filter `ls` output to only extract those files that have size more than 10k. In other words i want all those files that have file size of greater than 0. Here are the list of files that i am trying to filter

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 udevisetty services  455 Sep 19 13:53 RIL_131.01.bwa_tophat.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 udevisetty services    0 Sep 17 01:37 RIL_136.01.bwa_tophat.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 udevisetty services    0 Sep 18 02:34 RIL_143.01.bwa_tophat.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 udevisetty services    0 Sep 19 06:32 RIL_147.01.bwa_tophat.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 udevisetty services 1.4K Sep 19 15:05 RIL_150.01.bwa_tophat.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 udevisetty services  331 Sep 19 15:00 RIL_15.01.bwa_tophat.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 udevisetty services    0 Sep 17 21:18 RIL_171.01.bwa_tophat.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 udevisetty services    0 Sep 19 13:41 RIL_175.01.bwa_tophat.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 udevisetty services 1.5K Sep 19 15:13 RIL_176.01.bwa_tophat.err
```

Here is the command i am trying with no success.

```
find . -type f -size +10 -name "*.err"
```

Any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find all the files that are at least 10k, try this (you didn't specify the units so it used the default `b`, which is 512-byte blocks):

```
find . -type f -size +10k
```

Use this to list of all non-empty files:

```
find . -type f ! -size 0
```

To see `ls` output of those files, do something like this:

```
find . -type f ! -size 0 -exec ls -l '{}' \;
```